# Redirect to empty cart in AOL

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, cart

I have got complaints from few customers that some are not able to checkout on AOL browsers and they are redirected back to cart page with "empty cart" message.

> Cookie Lifetime   3600 
>  Cookie Path   
> Cookie Domain  
> Use
>   HTTP Only yes 
> Cookie Restriction Mode    NO 
> Session Validation
>   Settings no
>  Validate REMOTE_ADDR no 
> Validate HTTP_VIA
>   no 
> Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR no 
> Validate
>   HTTP_USER_AGENT   no 
> Use SID on Frontend      yes

After reading articles and post on forums I changed above settings to

> Cookie Lifetime   84600 
>  Cookie Path  
> Cookie Domain  
> Use
>   HTTP Only yes 
> Cookie Restriction Mode    NO 
> Session Validation
>   Settings no
>  Validate REMOTE_ADDR no 
> Validate HTTP_VIA
>   no 
> Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR no 
> Validate
>   HTTP_USER_AGENT   yes 
> Use SID on Frontend      no

After this, I am not able to browse my site on AOL and every link redirects me to home page. 
For now I have reverted back to my original seetings.
Did anyone face this type of issue? 
What is the cause of it and how can I fix the issue "redirected back to cart page with "empty cart" message"? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by AOL browser?

Comment: By AOL browser, I think customers are trying to say AOL desktop, but I am not 100% sure. I am working on AOL desktop 9.6

Answer (score 0):

This was a comment but I don't think it is readable and maybe in the end too long to be a comment.

*AOL browser: This thing still exists?*

Unfortunately I don't see any way how to reproduce this bug. So this question is off topic.

But a few ideas on this: What you have done made it worse. The option `Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT` adds more security. The option adds the browser to the session and checks whether the user agent changed. If yes, the session is destroyed.

I'm not 100% sure but I think `Use SID on Frontend` adds the session id to every link on the frontend, so this might help.

**What the problem is**: The concrete problem is unknown, but if the cart is empty two things can happen:

- the cart is cleared
- the session is destroyed

So to check the first one, reproduce the bug and check your session cookie `frontend` whether the session ID changed, if it is the case, you need to analyze why this happens. The problem is probably client side.

If the session ID is the same, then the cart was cleared, so here is the problem surely server side.